# How can I install VLC 1.1.10 or 1.1.9 in CentOS 5.6 or CentOS 6.0?

Tags: linux, fedora, centos, vlc

On the VLC download site there is no CentOS 5.6 or 6.0 downloads rpm's. Which RPM  can I use to have VLC 1.1.10? In case it's not available, can I simply use the same Fedora downloads?

```
[root@www ~]# uname -a
Linux www 2.6.18-194.11.4.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 21 05:04:09 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@www ~]# yum search vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * base: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * ius: mirror.rackspace.co.uk
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Warning: No matches found for: vlc
No Matches found
[root@www ~]#
```

Update: This is the error I get:

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:0.9.9a-7.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.52(LIBAVFORMAT_52)(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.50(LIBAVUTIL_50)(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.51(LIBPOSTPROC_51)(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.52(LIBAVCODEC_52)(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.0(LIBSWSCALE_0)(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libavcodec.so.52()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdvdnav.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdvbpsi.so.6()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libliveMedia.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libshout.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: liblirc_client.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libkate.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdvdread.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libavformat.so.52()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: liba52.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libXvMCW.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libzvbi.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdca.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libixml.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libcvaux.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libswscale.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libebml.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libid3tag.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_decoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libhighgui.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libcxcore.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libmpcdec.so.5()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libxosd.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libtwolame.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libfaad.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libpostproc.so.51()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libml.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libavutil.so.50()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libupnp.so.3()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libSDL_image-1.2.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libvgagl.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libBasicUsageEnvironment.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libmodplug.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libtag.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libdirac_encoder.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libUsageEnvironment.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libportaudio.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libgroupsock.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libaa.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libcddb.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libcaca.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libmpeg2.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libcv.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libvga.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libmad.so.0()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libmatroska.so.2()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Running transaction check
---> Package SDL_image.x86_64 0:1.2.10-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package a52dec.x86_64 0:0.7.4-8.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package aalib.x86_64 0:1.4.0-5.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package dirac.x86_64 0:1.0.2-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcppunit-1.12.so.0()(64bit) for package: dirac
---> Package faad2.x86_64 0:2.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package ffmpeg.x86_64 0:0.6.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libx264.so.107()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
--> Processing Dependency: libmp3lame.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
--> Processing Dependency: libopencore-amrnb.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
--> Processing Dependency: libopencore-amrwb.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
--> Processing Dependency: libfaac.so.0()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
--> Processing Dependency: libgsm.so.1()(64bit) for package: ffmpeg
---> Package ffmpeg-libpostproc.x86_64 0:0.6.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libcaca.x86_64 0:0.99-0.1.beta17.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libglut.so.3()(64bit) for package: libcaca
---> Package libcddb.x86_64 0:1.3.1-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libcdio.so.7(CDIO_7)(64bit) for package: libcddb
--> Processing Dependency: libcdio.so.7()(64bit) for package: libcddb
---> Package libdca.x86_64 0:0.0.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libdvbpsi.x86_64 0:0.1.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libdvdnav.x86_64 0:0.1.10-3.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libdvdread.x86_64 0:0.9.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libdvdcss >= 1.2.5 for package: libdvdread
---> Package libebml.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libid3tag.x86_64 0:0.15.1b-3.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libkate.x86_64 0:0.3.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libmad.x86_64 0:0.15.1b-4.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libmatroska.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libmodplug.x86_64 0:0.8.7-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libmpcdec.x86_64 0:1.2.6-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libshout.x86_64 0:2.2.2-2.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libupnp.x86_64 0:1.6.6-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package lirc.x86_64 0:0.6.6-4.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package live555.x86_64 0:0-0.27.2012.02.04.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package mpeg2dec.x86_64 0:0.4.1-2.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package opencv.x86_64 0:1.0.0-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package portaudio.x86_64 0:19-1.20071207.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package svgalib.x86_64 0:1.9.25-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package taglib.x86_64 0:1.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package twolame.x86_64 0:0.3.13-1.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libsndfile.so.1(libsndfile.so.1.0)(64bit) for package: twolame
--> Processing Dependency: libsndfile.so.1()(64bit) for package: twolame
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:0.9.9a-7.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXvMCW.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
---> Package xosd.x86_64 0:2.2.14-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package zvbi.x86_64 0:0.2.33-2.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cppunit.x86_64 0:1.12.0-3.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package faac.x86_64 0:1.26-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package gsm.x86_64 0:1.0.13-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package lame.x86_64 0:3.99.5-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libcaca.x86_64 0:0.99-0.1.beta17.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libglut.so.3()(64bit) for package: libcaca
---> Package libcdio.x86_64 0:0.77-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libdvdcss.x86_64 0:1.2.10-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package libsndfile.x86_64 0:1.0.17-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package opencore-amr.x86_64 0:0.1.2-1.el5.rf set to be updated
---> Package vlc.x86_64 0:0.9.9a-7.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXvMCW.so.1()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
--> Processing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) for package: vlc
---> Package x264.x86_64 0:0.0.0-0.4.20101111.el5.rf set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
libcaca-0.99-0.1.beta17.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libglut.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package libcaca-0.99-0.1.beta17.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libXvMCW.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 from rpmforge has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libglut.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package libcaca-0.99-0.1.beta17.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libXvMCW.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libQtCore.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
Error: Missing Dependency: libQtGui.so.4()(64bit) is needed by package vlc-0.9.9a-7.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
Restoring your Previous repositories......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works: https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=15725

```
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt
rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
rpm -i rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.*.rpm
yum -y install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can always try and see if the dependencies match up reasonably.

CentOS is not targeted at the desktop market where VLC is expected to run. If you expect this to be a multi-media machine maybe you should be using Fedora or another distro that your favorite software plays nice with.

Comment: VLC in CentOS is not for playing mutlimedia, just to capture remote location "vlc -I dummy rtsp://ip/video --sout=file/ogg:/tmp/RECORDING.ogg" to local file system and send it to NAS server. Where CentOS is required so that it has maximum server performence (instead of desktop Fedora performence/realiability).

Comment: I just logged in to my CentOS 5.4, and did some yum search nothing related to VLC is found. [root@www ~]# yum search vlc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * base: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * epel: mirror01.th.ifl.net
 * extras: mirror.netrino.co.uk
 * ius: mirror.rackspace.co.uk
 * updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Warning: No matches found for: vlc
No Matches found

Comment: How about using `mplayer`/`mencoder` instead of `vlc`? You can undoubtedly get vlc compiled for CentOS just fine but it will be easier to upgrade and admin in the future if you stick to packages in the repos.